# Spring @Configuration how to inject a @Bean in a map

Tags: spring, configuration

I work with Spring and I have the following bean declaration

```
Catalog
    private Map<String, Product> products;
```

I want to declare the beans with @Configuration

In  a java class I declared

```
@Bean(name="product_01")
    public Product product_01() {
        return new Product("0596009208","Head First Java","ea",new Float(26.07),22);
    }
```

Now I want to declare the bean catalog assign to the map Products the bean product_01.

Is it right this initialization?

```
@Bean(name="catalog")
    public Catalog catalog() {
            Catalog catalog1 = new Catalog();


            products.put(product_01().getSku(), product_01());

            catalog1.setProducts(products);

        return catalog1;
    }
```

I get a NullPointerException when bean catalog is created.

I want to inject the product_01 in the map products.

Comment: Just put `@Autowired` on the map. Spring will automatically give you all instances of the bean into the map (the string is the bean name in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1.

```
@Bean(name="catalog")
public Catalog catalog(Product product_01) {
  products.put(product_01().getSku(), product_01());
}
```

2. As @Deinum said you can do

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Product> products;
```

In this case Spring will autowire all instances of Products with their names as key

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is mention above, be sure to initialize the map before put statement `products = new HashMap<String,Product>()` as example